# How do I solve this mystery number problem?

Tags: c++, math

My problem is, I'm doing some practice while I'm sick and I don't go to school and I ran into a problem which I was solving whole last night, but looks so simple yet it is complicated, so here's the problem: 
/*Write a program where the user will load the three-digit integer and sums all digits of the number and calculates *a mystery number* with the following equation:

`mn = round((a^3+ b^2+c^ )/(a+2*b+3*c))`, where `a` is the first digit, `b` is the second digit and `c` is the third digit

In the first line of the console must be the sum of the digits and in the second has to be the mystery number.*/

And here's where I got the problem, no matter how many times I try it just prints that mystery number is 0, but the sum is alright, although I could write the code a bit better
here's the code:

```
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
       int n;
       int a, b, c, sum;
       double mn;

       printf("n = ");
       scanf("%d", &n);

       a = (n / 100);
       b = (n / 10) - a * 10;
       c = n - a * 100 - b * 10;

       sum = a + b + c;

       mn = round((a^3 + b^2 + c) / (a + 2 * b + 3 * c));

       printf("\nmn = %f", mn);
       printf("\nsum is = %d", sum);

       return 0;
```

For this code I used stdio.h and math.h. Help me. Please.

Comment: Are you aware that ^ in c/c++ is the xor bitwise operator instead of exponent?

Comment: @marko_vuger look for what `operator^` do actually

Comment: (a^3 + b^2 + c) / (a + 2 * b + 3 * c) != double(a * a * a + b * b + c)/(a + 2 * b + 3 * c)

Comment: @marko_vuger, as Asadefa said, try to use pow(a, 3) instead of a^3. pow is a function within the math.h library

Answer (score 3):

In `mn = round((a^3 + b^2 + c) / (a + 2 * b + 3 * c));`:

- `^` is not exponentiation; `a^3` does not calculate the cube of `a`.
- `(a^3 + b^2 + c)` and `(a + 2 * b + 3 * c)` are integer expressions, so `/` performs integer division, which truncates.

To calculate simple powers of integer values, simply multiply them as needed, such as `a*a*a` and `b*b`.

To perform floating-point division instead of integer division, convert either of the operands to `double`, as with `(double) (a*a*a + b*b + c)`.

Comment: ahh no I was chacing code while I was writing this question so I can adjust it to English, don't mind that

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the equation's result to *tb* and printing *mn*, which was never initialized and probably has 0 as its default value.

Comment: Objects with automatic storage duration, such as `mn`, are not initialized by default. The behavior of using such an object is generally not defined by the C standard. It may act in some cases as if it had the value zero, but we should not give students the impression it is initialized by default to zero or to any other value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil are you sure? I think it depends on the OS

Comment: Per C 2018 6.7.9 10, “If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate…” A C implementation could choose to extend the C standard by initializing automatic objects to zero (or equivalent) by default. This would be a choice of the C implementation; it can be independent of the operating system. However, it would be expensive in the sense it would require extra work for essentially all programs, and I am not aware of any implementation that has chosen to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t seem to store anything in variable mn, instead I see you’re using a variable named tb for you mystery number calculation. I also second the fact that the ^operator doesn’t do exponentiation, it is a bitwise xor.

Comment: That nondeclared tb is just a mistake while I was writing this question, I was adjusting my code to English, so it should basically be mn